# Density of Simple Functions in $L^1(G)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group.Thus we can define the Haar measure on $G$. Prove that span{$\chi_{E}:E\subseteq $$K$,$K$ is compact} is dense in $L^1(G)$. I know that functions in $L^1(G)$ can be approximated by just simple functions,but how do I prove this result? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to show that you can approximate every measurable set by compact sets. Regularity properties of Haar measures help.

Comment: I was also trying that way.But the approximation is from inside rather than outside.So can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Ah, you have even more. I thought you had only characteristic functions of compact sets. Doesn't make much of a difference, however. A Haar measure is inner regular on all $\sigma$-finite Borel sets, in particular on all Borel sets of finite measure. That suffices.

Comment: I am sorry,but I still cannot provide a rigorous proof.Please help.